# Conveying the sentence "The force can be seen physically as a push or a pull."

Tags: traduction, anglais, noms, physique

> The force can be seen physically as a push or a pull.

Deepl translates this sentence as

> La force peut être considérée physiquement comme une poussée ou une traction.

I am wondering if there is a more colloquial word for translating pull in this context, if one wishes to avoid the word traction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Je suggère :

> La force peut être considérée physiquement comme répulsive ou attractive.